# asp.net mvc multitenant (multiple projects management like structure)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, multi-tenant, asp.net-roles

I am looking for right word but I believe it has to be in direction of asp net multitenancy.

I dont need full multitenant site but I would like to design a site where managers of different divisions can log in. These managers are like admins in their divisions and can add users and assign edit, view rights to their users. Or we can think this of a site that has multiple projects. Project Manager is admin of each project, s/he can add new members to each project with different roles.

How can I go on using asp net roles and memberships to create such a dynamic structure ?

Using fixed roles as attribute is OK as long as whole site is only one division but for multiple divisions, I need to know dynamically does this user belong to one or many divisions, what are its roles in those divisions ?

Are there any good tutorials that I can start from ?